# Linking content from different fxml files

Tags: java, javafx, guice

I have a JavaFx project I created using SceneBuilder.
I am also using  a Guice plugin architecture.
I have one .fxml file that has a pane that I want to be the the content of another .fxml file. 
Is there any easy way to link .fxml content from one file to another?
I have not used fx.guice plugin architecture before. Is there an easier way to this with plugin control?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know fx.guice but can't you just use an [`<fx:include>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements)?

Answer (score 1):

This was a big problem for us since we also are using Guice and JavaFX.

tl;dr I've attached some code at the bottom that we've been using for a year and a bit now without issue.

edit: I should've mentioned we did all this stuff before fx,guice existed, so this exists entirely outside that, and I probably should be using it.

Yes, but you will have to modify the view tree from java, and you must instantiate two controllers. If you're willing to let the fxml loader instantiate your controllers (we're not, more in a sec), then you simply need to have code along the lines of

#### solution 1:

```
loadMergedView(){
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourOuterView.fxml"));   
    Pane outerRoot = fxmlLoader.load();

    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourInnerView.fxml"));
    Pane innerView = fxmlLoader.load();

    ((Region)outerRoot.getChildren().get(2))...getChildren().add(innerView);
}
```

which isn't nice because it means the FX loader will try to create your controller for you, *but you probably want guice to do that*

luckily you can call `setController` (or `setControllerFactory`) to leverage guice, so now we have

#### solution 2:

```
@Inject private OuterController outerController
@Inject private InnerController innerController

loadMergedView(){
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourOuterView.fxml"));   
    //using the setControllerFactory instead of the setController 
    //means you can still declare the controller type in FXML
    //which is good for our IDE intelliJ and general readability
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(() -> outerController);
    Pane outerRoot = fxmlLoader.load();

    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourInnerView.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(() -> innerController);
    Pane innerView = fxmlLoader.load();

    ((Region)outerRoot.getChildren().get(2))...getChildren().add(innerView);
}
```

which is better but requires a 3rd party to load your components. What you really want, a le dependency-injection, is to have the child view be resolved first and as part of the resolution of the parent view.

For us, this brings us to

#### Solution 3:

```
class OuterController{

    @FXML Pane rootPane;
    @FXML Stuff otherStuffBoundInFXML;
    @FXML AnchorPane innerContactPaneOne;

    @Inject
    public OuterController(InnerController inner, FXMLLoader loader){
    
        loader.setControllerFactory(type -> this);
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourOuterView.fxml"));
        loader.load();      
        
        innerContactPaneOne.getChildren().add(inner.getRootView());
        
    }
}

class InnerController{
    
    @FXML Pane innerContentPaneTwo; //this will be a child of PaneOne in OuterController
    @FXML Button otherStuff;
    
    @Inject
    public InnerController(FXMLLoader loader){
        loader.setControllerFactory(type -> this);
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/com/yourpkg/YourInnerVIew.fxml"));
        loader.load();
    }
    
    public Node getRootView(){
        return innerContentPaneTwo;
    }    
}

//with somebody calling
OuterController rootController = injector.getInstance(OuterController.class);
```

And finally, in the name of 'convention over configuration', we created a few classes (attached below) that attempt to 'automatically' find the view by reflecting on the controllers name (eg `OuterController`) and **assuming** that it will find an FXML view view in the same directory as the controller's class file with the word `controller` replaced with `view` (eg OuterView.fxml)). We also leveraged a neat trick in super-ctor-order in java to allow us to have pre-setup FXML values.

So now we get:

#### solution4 :

```
class OuterController extends PreloadedFX{

    @FXML Pane rootPane;
    @FXML Stuff otherStuffBoundInFXML;
    @FXML AnchorPane innerContactPaneOne;
    @FXML Checkbox importantCheckbox;
    @FXML Label importantLabel;
    
    // because of 'PrealoadedFX' getting called first, 
    // you can actually inline initialize object constants
    // like this
    private final ObservableBooleanValue isSelected = importantCheckbox.selectedProperty();
    
    // or using an initializer
    {
        int x = 4;
        importantLabel.setText(importantLable.getText() + x);
    }

    @Inject
    public OuterController(InnerController inner, FXMLLoader loader){
        super(loader);      
        
        innerContactPaneOne.getChildren().add(inner.getRootView());
        
    }
}

class InnerController extends PreloadedFX{
    
    @FXML Pane innerContentPaneTwo; //this will be a child of PaneOne in OuterController
    @FXML Button otherStuff;
    
    @Inject
    public OuterController(FXMLLoader loader){
        super(loader);
    }
    
    public Node getRootView(){
        return innerContentPaneTwo;
    }    
}

//with somebody calling
OuterController rootController = injector.getInstance(OuterController.class);
```

you can get the source code for the PreloadedFX and View-By-Convention code here:
https://gist.github.com/Groostav/ff35eb2d19b348f2e25c

which is as elegant as I've been able to make this particular union of frameworks.

Hope that helps!